# Map every key starting with the same char to wordlist

Tags: java, list, hashmap

How would you code a map so that the initial character of each word maps to the full word?

Considering a wordlist that contains:

- albert
- ben
- alice
- cecilia

The output should be `{a=[albert,alice], b=[ben], c=[cecilia]}`

This is what I have right now but I don't understand how to map each key to all the correspondent words.

The map is of type `Map<String, List<String>> bigMap;`

```
 protected WordStore(String file) {
    this.bigMap = new HashMap<>();
    String line = "";
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));)
    {
        this.wordlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        wordlist.add(file);
        while ( (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                bigMap.putIfAbsent(String.valueOf(line.charAt(0)), new ArrayList<>());
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read all the lines and add it to a `List<String>`. once that is done you can achieve the task at hand with a `groupingBy` collector.

```
this.bigMap = myList.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.substring(0, 1)));
```

or you can read the file and group all in one go like this:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(file))) {
     this.bigMap = stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.substring(0, 1)));
} catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or:

```
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(file))) {
            this.bigMap = br.lines()
                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.substring(0, 1)));
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was exhaustive. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without `BufferedReader` and simplify your whole code to this:

```
protected WordStore(String file) {
    this.bigMap = Files.lines(Paths.get(file))
                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(word -> word.substring(0, 1)));    
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that change the type of my map from Map<String, List<String>> to Map<Character, List<String>>?